# Produce boolean column based on (grouping + filter) condition

Tags: sql, pyspark

Consider this dataframe:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ['id-A5', 'A', 5, 0, 'id-A5'],
    ['id-A7', 'A', 7, 2, 'id-A5'],
    ['id-B0', 'B', 0, 0, 'id-B0'],
    ['id-B1', 'B', 1, 1, 'id-B0'],
    ['id-B2', 'B', 2, 1, 'id-B0']]
    ,
    ['id', 'group', 'i', 'j', 'target_id']
)

df.show()
'''
+-----+-----+---+---+---------+
|   id|group|  i|  j|target_id|
+-----+-----+---+---+---------+
|id-A5|    A|  5|  0|    id-A5|
|id-A7|    A|  7|  2|    id-A5|
|id-B0|    B|  0|  0|    id-B0|
|id-B1|    B|  1|  1|    id-B0|
|id-B2|    B|  2|  1|    id-B0|
+-----+-----+---+---+---------+
'''
```

I want to create a boolean column, desired to be:

```
'''
+-----+-----+---+---+---------+-----------------+
|   id|group|  i|  j|target_id|target_is_correct|
+-----+-----+---+---+---------+-----------------+
|id-A5|    A|  5|  0|    id-A5|             true|
|id-A7|    A|  7|  2|    id-A5|             true|
|id-B0|    B|  0|  0|    id-B0|             true|
|id-B1|    B|  1|  1|    id-B0|             true|
|id-B2|    B|  2|  1|    id-B0|            false|
+-----+-----+---+---+---------+-----------------+
'''
```

The condition is explained like this: For each row, compute the *difference* `i - j`, then find the target row, from the same `group` as the row, and whose `i` value is equal to *difference*. If the `id` of the target row is equal to the `target_id` of the row, then true.

(The data is taken to be cohesive, meaning that targets are always found and unique)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried using .take() and .filter() but couldn't get too far because I don't know how to pass non-literal parameters to those functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = df.withColumn('diff', F.col('i') - F.col('j'))
result_df = df.alias('a').join(df.alias('b'),(F.col('a.group') == F.col('b.group')) & (F.col('a.diff') == F.col('b.i')),'left')
condition = (F.col('a.target_id') == F.col('b.id'))
result_df = result_df.withColumn('target_is_correct', F.when(condition, F.lit(True)).otherwise(F.lit(False)))
display(result_df.select('a.id', 'a.group', 'a.i', 'a.j', 'a.target_id', 'target_is_correct'))

+-----+-----+---+---+---------+-----------------+
|   id|group|  i|  j|target_id|target_is_correct|
+-----+-----+---+---+---------+-----------------+
|id-A5|    A|  5|  0|    id-A5|             true|
|id-A7|    A|  7|  2|    id-A5|             true|
|id-B0|    B|  0|  0|    id-B0|             true|
|id-B1|    B|  1|  1|    id-B0|             true|
|id-B2|    B|  2|  1|    id-B0|            false|
+-----+-----+---+---+---------+-----------------+
```

Comment: `window_spec` is unused, correct?